# Count multiple column without using many temporary tables then join PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, group-by, count

I have data like this
[image: I have data like this]

I want to count edit: `distinct` group1 and group 2 `group by` the Time and Type. I make each a temporary table then `full outer join` (on time and type) so desire column like:

```
Time    Type    Count_Group1     Count_Group2
```

Any shorter way to do this?

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thank you, because im using mobile to write this questions

Comment: Before anything, consider re-factoring your table design for a normalized framework. You avoid complex querying in doing so. Columns and tables with numbered suffixes are usually sub-optimal schema. Aim for long not wide tables.

Answer (score 1):

This answers the original version of the question:

You can use a lateral join and aggregation:

```
select time, type, sum(in1), sum(in2)
from t cross join lateral
     (values (time1, group1, 1, 0), (time2, group2, 0, 1)
     ) v(time, grp, in1, in2)
group by time, type;
```

EDIT:

To count distinct values, use `count(distinct)`:

```
select v.time, t.type, count(distinct t.group1), count(distinct t.group2)
from t cross join lateral
     (values (t.time1), (time2)
     ) v(time)
group by v.time, t.type;
```

Comment: I want each column for group 1 and group 2 count. Why there is a grp column? @gordon

Comment: @HaoHao . . . Good point.  `grp` is not needed.  I removed it.

Comment: there is still 'grp' above, I replace that with 'type' my code say type is ambiguous, I didn't know about this type of join yet. @gordon

Comment: what is in1 and in2?

Comment: 1,0 and 0,1 also I hope you could explain more @gordon

Comment: I want to `count distinct the` ID of group1 and group2, you use `sum` so the result is not true yet.

Comment: @HaoHao . . . You modified the question *after* it was answers, which is generally a bad practice.  That invalidates the answer, which can attract downvotes.  In this case, though, I have provided an answer to the revised question.

Comment: thank you @gordon , it was helped by being more specific

Comment: I run the code and at some record it not show the right number compared to simple count though.. I think I will research this type of join more. Thanks